# How can I dynamically add git reviewers using powershell script?

Tags: git, powershell

I am working on a project where I want to add different reviewers for different branch of my repository.

I generally add reviewers with this command:

```
git push --receive-pack='git receive-pack --reviewer=abc.def --reviewer=john.doe' origin HEAD:refs/for/<branch_name>
```

Since I use powershell terminal I wrote few scripts to ease my work. How can I add different reviewers group dynamically based on my current repository branch?

So far my powershell function look like this...

```
$BranchReviewerMap = @{ 
    'devO' = "'git receive-pack --reviewer=abc.def --reviewer=efg.hij'"
    'devI' = "'git receive-pack --reviewer=m.ks --reviewer=t.ch --reviewer=imt.h'"
    'devT' = "'git receive-pack --reviewer=m.ks --reviewer=t.ch --reviewer=ay.an'"
    'test' = "'git receive-pack --reviewer=m.ks'"
}

function mkb_git_push {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
            [ValidateSet("merge", "commit", "test")]
            [String] $commit_type = "commit"
    )
    $default_commit = "commit"
    $test_commit = "test"
    Clear-Host

    # ===========>>> Please ignore below parts. These are working just fine <<<=========== #
    # Get Current branch
    $cur_branch = git branch --show-current
    # Some other calculation and logic, which works.
    # ===========>>> Please ignore above parts. These are working just fine <<<=========== #

    #Not able to make it work. Tried both from below two lines.
    $reviewer = [String] $BranchReviewerMap[$cur_branch]
    #$reviewer = $BranchReviewerMap[$cur_branch]
    git push --receive-pack=$reviewer origin HEAD:refs/for/$cur_branch
}
```

The error I get is..

> fatal: Gerrit Code Review: $reviewer: not found
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

I am not looking for any if()-else if()-else type solution.

FYI: This is my first post on. Kindly ignore my mistakes on the post.

Comment: Given that PowerShell variable `$reviewer` is _expanded_ (replaced with its value) in the `git` command, it is surprising that the string `$reviewer` would show up in the error message. Or does `$reviewer` have special meaning in the context of Gerrit?

Comment: All the issues here are PowerShell-specific; consider removing the [tag:git] tag. (I'm leaving it in since the `--receive-pack=...` part is a Git trick that many Git users might not be aware of. That particular part is already working fine for you though!)

Comment: @mklement0: Thank you very much for your kind suggestion. I'd definitely do so.

Now for your first comment, I tried other random variable name other than $reviewer/$reviewers. It  results the same. :(

Comment: @torek: I kept the git tag, because I am trying to build a git command dynamically. If someone tried something like this before, I'd like to know their suggestion/opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least *one* problem is in how you construct your hashtable:

Do not include *embedded* `'...'`-quoting in the entry values; *syntactic* quoting, during entry *definition*, is sufficient (you could use single-quoting here, given that the values don't reference PowerShell variables):

```
$BranchReviewerMap = @{ 
    'devO' = "git receive-pack --reviewer=abc.def --reviewer=efg.hij"
    'devI' = "git receive-pack --reviewer=m.ks --reviewer=t.ch --reviewer=imt.h"
    'devT' = "git receive-pack --reviewer=m.ks --reviewer=t.ch --reviewer=ay.an"
    'test' = "git receive-pack --reviewer=m.ks"
}
```

PowerShell will automatically ensure that `--receive-pack=$reviewer` is passed as a *single* argument to `git`.

**Caveat**: On Windows, if `$reviewer` contains *spaces* (as is the case here), PowerShell will wrap the *entire* argument in `"..."` behind the scenes rather than just the part after `=`.

E.g., the actual Windows command line used *behind the scenes* may look something like this:

```
# Command line actually used, as rebuilt by PowerShell behind the scenes. 
git push "--receive-pack=git receive-pack --reviewer=m.ks" origin HEAD:refs/for/test
```

However, it appears that `git` on Windows accepts this quoting style; by contrast, other CLIs with similar options may not, such as `msiexec`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification how the internal command is working. As you suggested, I also tried with removing the single quote too from the Map. But the result is always same. I have been trying to solve this challenge for last couple of days and tried all sorts of combination for the quote/single quote.... but no luck so far... :(

Comment: @MuhammadRakeeb, following up on my comment above: If `$reviewer` refers to your _PowerShell_ variable, then it shouldn't appear in the _error message_, because in the command shown in the question `$reviewer` is _expanded_ (replaced by its value) before `git` ever sees the argument. In other words: the command you're showing in the question is probably not the same as the one that triggers your error.

Comment: @MuhammadRakeeb, note that if you had the following _typo_ in your real command, `$reviewer` would _not_ be expanded - due to a bug in PowerShell's parameter parsers - which in turn would explain why `$reviewer` shows up as a literal in your error message: `-receive-pack=$reviewer` - note the missing second `-` at the start.

Comment: Following the clue in your comment, I am finally able to solve it with another way. Using **Invoke-Expression**
Initially I build up the full command as a string and later executed it with Invoke-Expression. Here is my final code....

Comment: `$reviewers = $ProjectReviewerMap2[$cur_branch]
$part1="git push --receive-pack="
$part2="'"
$part3=" origin HEAD:refs/for/$cur_branch"
$final_cmd = $part1+$part2+$reviewers+$part2+$part3

# Test print
Write-Host $final_cmd -ForegroundColor "red"
Invoke-Expression -Command $final_cmd`

Comment: Not sure going through this worth it, but your comment on how the command was working internally gave me a better understanding.
Thanks a lot for that... :D

Comment: Glad to hear my pointers were helpful, @MuhammadRakeeb, but note that **[`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)** - and there's no good reason to use it in your case. Looking at your final code, I don't see how it would work differently than the preferred direct invocation.